# What is preferred way to show DOM elements conditioned on firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, server-side, client-side

I'm trying to build a small web-page where sign-in is controlled by Firebase Google Auth and is popped up with profile page. What is the secured and preferred way to show the profile page?

Currently I am using `onAuthStateChanged` to manipulate particular div which holds profile data when user is signed-in. If the user is not logged in I am using `removeChild()` method to remove that div from DOM and when logged in `appendChild()` adds back the div.

Comment: What are your 'security' concerns with the profile div showing prematurely, as presumably the data will be stored in Firebase which the user will need to log into before accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you're using `firebase`'s native [`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) function

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

As well as `firebase.auth().currentUser` to check if the user is currently logged in or not.

In that case, it's perfectly fine to use `removeChild` and `appendChild` and they do not hold any security threats, as if a user is not logged, after a page refresh all of the information will vanish.

Here's a small firebase application that shows that when the connection to the firebase is closed and `removeChild` is used, `appendChild` stops working as firebase is disconnected, thus proving the point that it's safe to use.

https://jsfiddle.net/vh9xay6e/

Note that in this example I'm not testing any authentification, just the use of firebase with `removeChild` and `appendChild`.

You can see that once the connection to Firebase is over, nothing on the frontend side can happen to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `onAuthStateChanged`  method we can act upon state change (sign in or Sign out)

As an example :

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{ 
  if(user){
    document.getElementById("id").classList.remove('hide')
    //this will populate your class which associate with above id.
  } else{
    document.getElementById("id_of_your_div").classList.add('hide')
  }
})
```

I think it's okay to use [`removeChild`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp) and [`appendChild`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) method based on firebase auth state changes in your application.

Answer (score 0):

try to wire around  your code by:
var userCurrent = firebase.auth().currentUser; in a function.

NOTE: Make sure you need to be sure first you signed in (as its an async operation), followed by the update user data as:

```
       var authenticationRef = firebase.auth();
    authenticationRef.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log('onAuthStateChanged : '+user.displayName);
            _updateUser();
        } else {
            console.log('Not login');
        }
    });

    fucntion _updateUser(){
      var userCurrent = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        userCurrent.updateProfile({
        displayName: "Karthik.S",
      }).then(function() {
        var displayName = userCurrent.displayName;
      }, function(error) {

      });
  }
```